# SEO and magic numbers in URL

Tags: seo

which URL is more relevant, 1 or 2?

1: http://site.com/language/countrcy/city/category/title

2: http://site.com/language/country/city/category/articleId(number)/title

the thing is I have to design my DB in ineffective way for (1) doing textual search and table joins, but I'm not sure how (2) where I'm just putting a direct table ID loses relevance in search results.

Answer (score 2):

The first would be the most relevant, as it doesn't contain any irrelevant data, such as the `articleId`.

If you are concerned about keeping unique titles, have a 2nd database column called `filename` for example, which is a URL encoded version of the `title`. If the title is already in use, then append an incremented value at the end.

For example, if the `title` 'SEO' was already in use by another article, loop through your string and call it `SEO-1` etc..

That way you are only applying irrelevant values when two titles clash.